# HTML Table to be condensed in Desktop but Responsive in Mobile Devices

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive

My Requirement is to have the HTML Table being Condensed on Desktop but skewed in a mobile.

For such, if I could by apply the Bootstrap style `table table-condensed` on a desktop/laptop but on a mobile device it should only have the style `table table-responsive`. I need this to be applied into entire web application or a certain page in a web application; whichever is feasible.

Effectively,

On a Desktop:

`<table class='table table-condensed'></table>`

On Mobile

`<table class='table table-responsive></table>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4 you can use breakpoint specific classes like `table-responsive-sm` to only apply it's styles on mobile. For desktop you can then create a media query for your class `table-condensed` (which is not part of Bootstrap) in CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/thzrq5a0/

```css
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .table-responsive-sm {
      background: red;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .table-condensed {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive-sm table-condensed">
  <table class="table">
    <caption>List of users</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```